# Problema CSS, não funciona

Tags: html, css

Alguns comandos em CSS não estão funcionando.

Segue os comandos:

**HTML**

```
 <section class="menu-departamentos"><!-- inicio .menu-departamentos -->

<h2>Departamentos</h2>

<nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Blusas e Camisas</a></li>
                        <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">Manga curta</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Manga cumprida</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Camisa social</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Camisa casual</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Calças</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Saias</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Vestidos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sapatos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Bolsas e Carteiras</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Acessórios</a></li>
                </ul>
</nav>

</section><!-- fim .menu-departamentos -->
```

**CSS**

```
   a[href^=http://]:after {
  content: '(externo)';
}


li ul {
    display: none;
}
```

Não faz o que era pra fazer, eu posso colocar `color:red;` no segundo que nada acontece.

Nada que eu coloque entre chaves funciona com o `li ul` separado por espaço, só funciona se eu separá-los por virgula `li,ul`.

Alguém sabe me dizer o porque?

Já testei com Chrome e com o Safira, ambos atualizados.

Uso o Sublime Text.

**Objetivo**

Retirar o submenu de **Blusas e Camisas** utilizando `display:none;` no CSS

Comment: Posta o HTML também. Mas assim, está errado.

Comment: @DiegoSouza Coloquei o **HTML** e mais algumas explicações, se puder me ajudar, eu agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

**Correção**

Amigo meu descobriu o problema (estava bem debaixo dos meus olhos).

**Segue a correção:**

```
    <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Blusas e Camisas</a></li> <!-- Esse </li> era o erro. -->
             <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Manga curta</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Manga cumprida</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Camisa social</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Camisa casual</a></li>
             </ul>

<!-- Aqui embaixo do </ul> deveria fechar o </li>, para o  css identificar que é um submenu -->

         <li><a href="#">Calças</a></li>

    </ul>
```

**Código correto:**

```
    <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Blusas e Camisas</a>
             <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Manga curta</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Manga cumprida</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Camisa social</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Camisa casual</a></li>
             </ul>
         </li>  
         <li><a href="#">Calças</a></li>

    </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul li ul{
    display:none;
}
```

**Motivo**

O motivo pelo qual o código não estava dando certo, era porque não fechei o li do submenu como explicado acima.

**Agradecimento**

Obrigado a **todos** que tentaram de alguma forma me ajudar a solucionar o problema,  que no caso foi minha falta de atenção ao código.
Ignorei totalmente revisar o HTML.

Que fique de aprendizado para os futuros leitores desse tópico, se o seu CSS não funcionar, procure revisar seu HTML, ele pode estar errado, O que pode influenciar ao tentar usar o CSS.

Answer (score -1):

```
li ul
```

O comando acima não é sequência, então se fizer isso não vai funcionar mesmo.

O certo seria assim:

```
ul li
```

Porque no **HTML** é assim:

```
<ul>
   <li> 1 </li>
   <li> 1 </li>
   <li> 1 </li>
</ul>
```

Se você separar por vírgula vai funcionar, porquê o CSS não entende como sequência e sim como tags separadas.

`ul, li` = `li, ul`

Comment: Você foi quem chegou mais próximo da solução do problema. 

meu código é esse, quero que o "submenu" de **Blusas e Camisetas**não apareça.

segue o Código:

Comment: Mas qual o seu problema ? Eu te expliquei o porquê não está funcionando o que você quer.

Comment: Coloquei o HTML e mais algumas explicações, se puder me ajudar, eu agradeço.

Comment: css utiliza elementos em cascata, você poderia fazer de duas maneiras: 

1ª: ul li ul li {display:none};

2ª: você poderia acrescentar uma classe nos <li> ou <ul> que deseja ocultar e o css referenciar a mesma. Exemplo: 
HTML:<li><a class='submenu' href="#">Manga curta</a></li> ou 
HTML:<ul class='submenu' >...</ul>
CSS: .submenu{display:none;}

Comment: Por que eu fui negativado ? Legal isso, hein! O cara posta uma pergunta mal feita, eu tento ajudar, ainda peço para ele postar mais coisas. Daí vem alguém e negativa.